# How do I stop awaiting a task but keep the task running in background?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

If I have a list of tasks which I want to execute together but at the same time I want to execute a certain number of them together, so I await for one of them until one of them finishes, which then should mean awaiting should stop and a new task should be allowed to start, but when one of them finishes, I don't know how to stop awaiting for the task which is currently being awaited, I don't want to cancel the task, just stop awaiting and let it continue running in the background.

I have the following code

```
foreach (var link in SharedVars.DownloadQueue)
{
    if (currentRunningCount != batch)
    {
        var task = DownloadFile(extraPathPerLink, link, totalLen);
        _ = task.ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            downloadQueueLinksTasks.Remove(task);
            currentRunningCount--;
            // TODO SHOULD CHANGE WHAT IS AWAITED
        });
        currentRunningCount++;
        downloadQueueLinksTasks.Add(task);
    }

    if (currentRunningCount == batch)
    {
        // TODO SHOULD NOT AWAIT 0
        await downloadQueueLinksTasks[0];
    }
}
```

I found about `Task.WhenAny` but from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427636/6877477) here I understood that the other tasks will be ignored so it's not the solution I want to achieve.

I'm sorry if the question is stupid or wrong but I can't seem to find any information related on how to solve it, or what is the name of the operation I want to achieve so I can even search correctly.

### Solution Edit

**All the answers provided are correct**, I accepted the one I decided to use but still all of them are correct.

Thank you everyone, I learned a lot from all of you from these different answers and different ways to approach the problem and how to think about it.

What I learned about this specific problem was that I still needed to await for the other tasks left, so the solution was to have the `Task.WhenAny` inside the loop (which returns the finished task (this is also important)) **AND** `Task.WhenAll` outside the loop to await the other left tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the Task which completed.

```
foreach (var link in SharedVars.DownloadQueue)
{
    var task = DownloadFile(extraPathPerLink, link, totalLen);
    downloadQueueLinksTasks.Add(task);

    if (downloadQueueLinksTasks.Count == batch)
    {
        // Wait for any Task to complete, then remove it from
        // the list of pending tasks.
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadQueueLinksTasks);
        downloadQueueLinksTasks.Remove(completedTask);
    }
}

// Wait for all of the remaining Tasks to complete
await Task.WhenAll(downloadQueueLinksTasks);
```

Comment: But this won't let the other tasks execute in batch as well, for example if batch is set to 5, I want to have at max 5 tasks executing at once but once one of them finishes, another one should start but not all the others (the others should wait in the same way)

Comment: Yes, that is what this code does. The Tasks are executing whether they're being awaited or not. This code starts 5 Tasks, then waits until one of them finishes. When one finishes, it removes it from `downloadQueueLinksTasks`, starts another Task, and waits for the next one to finish. Try it out and see.

Comment: Oh my god, the solution works, it works exactly as I planned, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Task.WaitAny()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAny_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___)

Here is the demonstration of the behavior:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(TestAsync(0));
    tasks.Add(TestAsync(1));
    tasks.Add(TestAsync(2));
    tasks.Add(TestAsync(3));
    tasks.Add(TestAsync(4));
    tasks.Add(TestAsync(5));

    var result = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("returned task id is {0}", result);

    ///do other operations where

    //before exiting wait for other tasks so that your tasks won't get cancellation signal
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

}

public static async Task TestAsync(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Staring to wait" + i);
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 10000));
    Console.WriteLine("Task finished" + i);
}
```

Output:

```
Staring to wait0
Staring to wait1
Staring to wait2
Staring to wait3
Staring to wait4
Staring to wait5
Task finished0
returned task id is 0
Task finished4
Task finished2
Task finished1
Task finished5
Task finished3
```

Comment: When I try using that for some reason after the first batch executes, the for loop exits, but when I try to use a debugger line by line it works as expected (I can press continue after a few lines and it'll continue working perfectly).

Comment: because you are terminating your application. eventually you need to await your tasks. . check my edited answer please

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that line, I didn't include it at all, I thought the inner Task.WhenAny will do the job but forgot that some tasks will not reach it because of the `if`s I had.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is *throttling*, which for asynchronous code is best expressed via `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(batch);
var tasks = SharedVars.DownloadQueue.Select(link =>
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try { return DownloadFile(extraPathPerLink, link, totalLen); }
  finally { semaphore.Release(); }
});
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    SharedVars.DownloadQueue
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(link =>
            Observable.FromAsync(() => DownloadFile(extraPathPerLink, link, totalLen)))
        .Merge(batch) //max concurrent downloads
        .Subscribe(file =>
        {
            /* process downloaded file here
               (no longer a task) */
        });
```

If you need to stop the downloads before they would naturally finish just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: This looks promising, but I have one question since I can't find any information regarding it, is Rx cross platform? Since it depends on .Net Framework and not on .Net Core I'm confused.